# how to make an array object (string) into a workable list using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data parsed and example cell looks like this when you do `df['text'].values`

```
['[\'Color is not claimed as a feature of the mark.\', \'"BRICKS"\', \'The mark consist of the stylized word "PIX" with an image of a toy block to the right and the stylized word "BRIX" appearing below.\', "Children\'s toys, namely, toy building and construction blocks and interlocking toy building and construction blocks", \'PIX BRICKS\']'],
      dtype=object)
```

However, I want to break the data into multiple lists, something similar to this format, but each list contains those info in one cell ['color is not claimed as a feature], ['bricks']...

```
20523203       Color is not claimed as a feature of the mark.
20523204                                             "BRICKS"
20523205    The mark consist of the stylized word "PIX" wi...
20523206    Children's toys, namely, toy building and cons...
20523207                                           PIX BRICKS
```

any suggestions on how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [6]: data
Out[6]: ['[\'Color is not claimed as a feature of the mark.\', \'"BRICKS"\', \'The mark consist of the stylized word "PIX" with an image of a toy block to the right and the stylized word "BRIX" appearing below.\', "Children\'s toys, namely, toy building and construction blocks and interlocking toy building and construction blocks", \'PIX BRICKS\']']

In [7]: # you need to remove [ and ] from the data

In [8]: clean_data = data[0].strip('[').strip(']')

In [9]: clean_data
Out[9]: '\'Color is not claimed as a feature of the mark.\', \'"BRICKS"\', \'The mark consist of the stylized word "PIX" with an image of a toy block to the right and the stylized word "BRIX" appearing below.\', "Children\'s toys, namely, toy building and construction blocks and interlocking toy building and construction blocks", \'PIX BRICKS\''

In [10]: # then split the data

In [11]: clean_data.split(',')
Out[11]: 
["'Color is not claimed as a feature of the mark.'",
 ' \'"BRICKS"\'',
 ' \'The mark consist of the stylized word "PIX" with an image of a toy block to the right and the stylized word "BRIX" appearing below.\'',
 ' "Children\'s toys',
 ' namely',
 ' toy building and construction blocks and interlocking toy building and construction blocks"',
 " 'PIX BRICKS'"]
```

Comment: i'm sure you can take it from here